# How to create hot key

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

In my Grails application called fleet management system trip creation is the basic function. I want to provide hot key ( like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>), on pressing the hot key it should open trip creation page. Is there anyway to do that using jquery ?
how about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> key combination ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys) plugin looks viable

### Example:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+c', fn);
```